# overlay data in grafan dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I just started to play around with managed Grafana/Prometheus in Azure monitor workspace to monitor pod mem/cpu consumption for application deployed in AKS cluster.

I found the below dashboard particularly useful, and I want to edit it so that I could overlay the cpu usage of pod0 and pod1 onto the same graph for easy comparison; so I cloned datasource A as datasource D as in the below screen, but somehow the data seems to be displayed in the way that c1 data is added on top of c0 data, instead of overlay.

how do I change this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for Graph styles>Stack series in panel options?